# Simple Search trouble on ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch 2.1. I'm not quite figuring out what I'm doing wrong. It baffles me the differents between queries, filters... Could you help me please?

I'm trying to perform this query. It returns me an empty result:

```
curl -XGET 'http://ESNode01:9201/living_team/inputs/_search?pretty' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": { 
            "query": { "match_all": {} },
            "filter": { "term": { "channel": "Feina" } }
        }
     }
}
'
```

However, when I perform this query without filters it returns me everything:

```
curl -XGET 'http://ESNode01:9201/living_team/inputs/_search?pretty' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": { 
            "query": { "match_all": {} },
        }
     }
}
'
```

This is a document sample:

```
{
  "user":"living_team",
  "timestamp":"2015-12-14T18:06:47.085Z",
  "matter":"snip2.PNG",
  "comment":"Archive",
  "channel":"Feina",
  "feedTypes":[
     20
  ],
  "property_general_ldate":"2015-12-14T18:06:47.085Z",
  "property_tSize":7595.0,
  "resources":[
     {
        "timestamp":"2015-12-14T16:58:00.598Z",
        "matter":"snip2.PNG",
        "comment":"Archive",
        "channel":"Feina",
        "feedType":20,
        "mime":"image/png",
        "source":{
           "sourceId":{
              "id":"C:\\Users\\Beep\\Desktop\\share\\snip2.PNG",
              "batch":"c38eec2d-a282-11e5-baf4-382c4ab9e433",
              "client":"VIM12HCNZL"
           },
           "feedType":20,
           "property_folder":"C:\\Users\\Beep\\Desktop\\share",
           "property_lastAccessFolder_ldate":1450111821506
        },
        "property_size":7595.0,
        "property_creation_ldate":"2015-12-14T16:50:20.578Z",
        "property_name":"snip2.PNG",
        "nestedResources":[

        ]
     }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
curl - XGET 'http://ESNode01:9201/living_team/inputs/_search?pretty' - d ' {
{
    "query": {"match": {
       "channel": "feina"    }}
}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `channel` field is probably `analyzed` and hence it is indexed as a lowercased string. The following query will work instead (i.e. with `feina` in lowercase):

```
curl -XGET 'http://ESNode01:9201/living_team/inputs/_search?pretty' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": { 
            "query": { "match_all": {} },
            "filter": { "term": { "channel": "feina" } }
        }
     }
}
'
```

Another solution is to make your `channel` field a `not_analyzed` string in your mapping and your `term` filter would work with `Feina` (but not with `feina` anymore). In the end it depends on how you want to store and search your data.

Comment: IMHO it should be solved not by lowercasing it manually but adding lowercase search analyzer.

Comment: The `term` filter doesn't analyze anything. The `match` query could be used instead and that would also do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried with `term filter -> "feina"` and with `match filter -> "FeINa"`, and they returns the documents correctly. However, If I want that matches words like "fein", "fen", "EIna", and so on... What would I do to solve that?

Comment: Nice! Matching "fein", "fen", "EIna" is a different issue which warrants a dedicated question of its own.