# Query by UUID format-like field on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I've indexed documents like that's been created on the fly, so I mean the mapping has been created on at the same time new fields were created (dynamically).

```
{
  "user":"living_team",
  "timestamp":"2015-12-14T18:06:47.085Z",
  "matter":"snip2.PNG",
  "comment":"Archive",
  "channel":"Feina",
  "feedTypes":[
     20
  ],
  "property_general_ldate":"2015-12-14T18:06:47.085Z",
  "property_tSize":7595.0,
  "resources":[
     {
        "timestamp":"2015-12-14T16:58:00.598Z",
        "matter":"snip2.PNG",
        "comment":"Archive",
        "channel":"Feina",
        "feedType":20,
        "mime":"image/png",
        "source":{
           "sourceId":{
              "id":"C:\\Users\\Beep\\Desktop\\share\\snip2.PNG",
              "batch":"c38eec2d-a282-11e5-baf4-382c4ab9e433",
              "client":"VIM12HCNZL"
           },
           "feedType":20,
           "property_folder":"C:\\Users\\Beep\\Desktop\\share",
           "property_lastAccessFolder_ldate":1450111821506
        },
        "property_size":7595.0,
        "property_creation_ldate":"2015-12-14T16:50:20.578Z",
        "property_name":"snip2.PNG",
        "nestedResources":[

        ]
     }
  ]
```

}

I need to get documents that: `resources.source.sourceId.id is exactly "X"`. I've tried with this query, however its results is empty.

```
curl -XGET 'http://ESNode01:9201/living_team/inputs/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query":{
     "filtered":{
        "query":{
           "term":{
              "resources.source.sourceId.batch":"3fcb8905-a307-11e5-88de-382c4ab9e433"
           }
        },
        "filter":{
           "match":{
              "channel":"FeINa"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's the same issue as in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34284094/simple-search-trouble-on-elasticsearch), namely that the `resources.source.sourceId.batch` string field has been created as an `analyzed` field and thus the value `c38eec2d-a282-11e5-baf4-382c4ab9e433` has been tokenized into the five tokens `c38eec2d`, `a282`, `11e5`, `baf4`, `382c4ab9e433`.

The correct way to handle this is to set a specific `not_analyzed` mapping for that field.

Another temporary way out of this would be to use a `query_string` query with an exact match:

```
curl -XGET 'http://ESNode01:9201/living_team/inputs/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query":{
     "filtered":{
        "query":{
           "query_string":{
              "query": "resources.source.sourceId.batch:\"3fcb8905-a307-11e5-88de-382c4ab9e433\""
           }
        },
        "filter":{
           "match":{
              "channel":"FeINa"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you don't want to add each UUID fields in your template you can use the `terms` condition instead or `term` and split your UUID string on each `-`.

I'm not sure about the performance... but it does the trick.

You should have something like that in your query:

```
curl -XGET 'http://ESNode01:9201/living_team/inputs/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query":{
     "filtered":{
        "query":{
           "terms":{
              "resources.source.sourceId.batch":["3fcb8905", "a307", "11e5", "88de", "382c4ab9e433"]
           }
        },
        "filter":{
           "match":{
              "channel":"FeINa"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}'
```